# how to update values in Firestore database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update values (isComplete) in Firestore database. I will not know the document id but I am trying to update values where "description" = 123 and "remindTime" = 11 am

```
const todoRef = db.collection("todo");

const isComplete = (date) => {
  return todoRef
    .where("description", "==", 123)
    .where("remindTime", "==","11 am")
    .update({
      isComplete: true,
    });
};
```

Comment: I suggest renaming your function from `isComplete` to `markAsCompleted` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the document ID (or have a [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) to it) to update it. Try the following function:

```
const todoRef = db.collection("todo");

const isComplete = async (date) => {
  const todoDoc = await todoRef
    .where("description", "==", 123)
    .where("remindTime", "==","11 am")
    .get()
  if (todoDoc.empty) return "No TODO found"
  return todoDoc.docs[0].ref.update({isComplete: true})
};
```

Comment: `return await` is superfluous, just use return directly. Also, you'd need to use `todoDoc.docs[0]` as `todoDoc[0]` would be `undefined`.